# how to manage tab loader in browsers?

Tags: ajax, web, browser

I'm trying to manage (when to start and stop running) loader that appears behind the tab name, the loader indicates that there is requests behind the seen, any help?.[tab loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61b3e.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean the loading indicator in Chrome browser tabs? If so, no, that can't be done.

Comment: yes, i meant that spinner. thank you. @heylookltsme